# SQL Server 2012 Column Level Encryption

Tags: sql, encryption

Is it possible to encrypt the column level data with a PASSWORD to be secure?  because if unknown person knows these certificate NAMES and key NAMES  they can open and decry pt and see the data. Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ms179331.aspx#TsqlProcedure

Answer (score 0):

The column to be encrypted should be a varbinary(256)

```
DECLARE @Password varchar(128)
SET @Password = 'your password'
INSERT INTO MyTable ( ..., MyEncryptedColumn, ...)
VALUÈS(..., EncryptByPassPhrase(@Password, 'your secret'), ...)
```

To decrypt use:

```
SELECT fieldname = CONVERT(nvarchar(25), DecryptByPassPhrase(@Password, MyEncryptedColumn))
FROM MyTable
```

Hope this helps